# reading files python

Tags: python, file, readfile

I want to read files in an advanced mode.

**First:**

In this file, I have certain steps with which the code has to follow, how do I read the steps until the string `[data]` appears.

```
[Steps]
step1 = WebAddress
step2 = Tab
step3 = SecurityType
step4 = Criteria
step5 = Date
step6 = Click1
step7 = Results
step8 = Download
[data]
......
```

**Second:**
How can I read all everything after [data].

```
[data]
WebAddress___________________________ Destination___________ Tab_____________ SecurityType___________________________________________________ Criteria___ Date_______ Click1_ Results_ Download    
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Interim MBS: Single-Family                                      Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Preliminary Mega: Fannie Mae/Ginnie Mae backed Adjustable Rate  Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/  q:\\%s\\raw\\fnmapool  Advanced Search  Preliminary Mega: Fannie Mae/Ginnie Mae backed Fixed Rate       Issue Date  09/01/2012  Search  100      CSV XML
```

I want to pass everything under the `step____________________` where step can be the steps(e.g. WebAddress).
So for example, if `step1 = WebAddress` how do I read everything under `WebAddress__________________________` and so on? Thanks!

Comment: How big is the file?  Is it big enough where you want to avoid reading it all into memory at once?

Comment: It is not very big, at most in some cases it will reach maybe 1 MB

Comment: I have tried using loops, but it is too tedious.

Comment: Still, @user1582983, could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: related: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
 with open(file_name) as f:
      print (f.read()).split("[data]")
```

Second:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
      pre_data,post_data =[s.strip() for s in (f.read()).split("[data]")]
post_data_lines = post_data.splitlines()
headers = post_data_lines[0].split()
print headers
for line in post_data_lines[1:]:
      print line.split()
      print dict(zip(headers,line.split()))
```

Im also not sure how your [data]is delimited you may want `line.split('\t')` if its tabbed

this is untested... but it should work and it doesnt quite get you all the way where you want but at least it gets most  of what your want (the "hard" parts)

to split by header width use

```
file_name = "testdata.txt"
with open(file_name) as f:
      pre_data,post_data =[s.strip() for s in (f.read()).split("[data]")]
post_data_lines = post_data.splitlines()
headers = post_data_lines[0].split()

for line in post_data_lines[1:]:
    tmpline  = []
    pos = 0
    for itm in headers:
        tmpline.append(line[pos:pos+len(itm)])
        pos += len(itm)+1

    print dict(zip(headers,tmpline))
```

and if you want the actual header with out the **__**'s then use

```
file_name = "testdata.txt"
with open(file_name) as f:
      pre_data,post_data =[s.strip() for s in (f.read()).split("[data]")]
post_data_lines = post_data.splitlines()
headers = post_data_lines[0].split()
headers2 = [s.replace("_"," ").strip() for s in headers]
for line in post_data_lines[1:]:
    tmpline  = []
    pos = 0
    for itm in headers:
        tmpline.append(line[pos:pos+len(itm)])
        pos += len(itm)+1

    print dict(zip(headers2,tmpline))
```

Comment: The second part doesnt work, it is not reading everything under the `headers`, it only gives me one character.

Comment: But then it breaks the word if it has a space, for example if it was just "hello world" it only assigns "hello" under the header.

Comment: yeah ... as I said im not sure how your data is delimited ... if its tabs you can split on \t instead ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16058/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-user1582983)

Answer (score 0):

First step:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> cfg = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
>>> with open('sample.cfg') as f:
...     cfg.readfp(f)
... 
>>> cfg.get('Steps','step1')
'WebAddress'
```

Second step:

```
>>> data_section = ''
>>> with open('sample.cfg') as f:
...    data_section = f.read()
... 
>>> data = data_section[data_section.index('[data]')+len('[data]')+1:]
>>> reader = csv.reader(io.BytesIO(data),delimiter='\t')
>>> reader.next() # skips header
>>> results = [row for for row in reader]
```

Now results is a list of lists, with each inner list having items from the data section.

```
[['https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/','q:\\\\%s\\\\raw\\\\fnmapool','Advanced Search', 'Interim MBS: Single-Family', 'Issue Date','09/01/2012','Search','100', 'CSV XML']...]
```